# "Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in eval()" when concatenating several text fields

Tags: 7, entities

I am using Computed Field to concatenate a few text fields into one value. The text fields are pieces of a street address (the street address, the city, the state, and the zip code). When using the code below, I receive the error below.

COMPUTED CODE:

> $entity_field[0]['value'] =
>   array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity,
>   'field_address'))) . ', ' .
>   array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity,
>   'field_city'))) . ', ' .
>   array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity,
>   'field_state'))) . ' ' .
>   array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity,
>   'field_zip_code')));

DISPLAY CODE:

> $display_output = $entity_field_item['value'];

ERROR:

> Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in eval()
>   (line 1 of
>   /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/computed_field/computed_field.module(468)
>   : eval()'d code).

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_address')));
```

=>

```
$items = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_address'));
$entity_field[0]['value'] = array_pop($items);
```

You have to store result of function in variable and pass it to another function, instead of pass function to function.

[Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! I am a little unclear on how to apply this code to all of the fields that I need to combine. Can you please show me how the full code snippet would look?

Comment: I would recommend you to use Entity metadata wrappers to get entity's values, these links can explain how to:   
https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers,    
http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/how-use-entity-metadata-wrappers-drupal-7/,    
http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/entity-metadata-wrapper